# convert CString to CTime

Tags: mfc

In **smart device MFC application**:

I have successfully converted `CTime` to `CString`. Now I want to convert it back, `CString` to `CTime`. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `COleDateTime::ParseDateTime(CString)` and then convert it to CTime.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16737338/731081) for the conversion to CTime

Answer (score 1):

Check out the example mentioned in this MSDN doc page: [COleDateTime::ParseDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37t16xc9%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Your link no longer works, it takes you to a page to download the help for VS 2013.  this one works now, who knows if it will work in the future: [COleDateTime::ParseDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=msvc-170#parsedatetime)