# How to save datetime in EDB database

Tags: datetime, mfc, windows-ce

I want to save datetime into the EDB database. I tried storing the value by converting CTime to CString. But after reading not able to convert CString to Ctime. Ask the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411967/convert-cstring-to-ctime) on stackoverflow, yet no responses.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885368.aspx) are EDB database datatypes. Can I use `CEVT_FILETIME`? If possible please give me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SystemTimeToFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908968.aspx) then store it as a `CEVT_FILETIME`.