# How to convert CString to CTime in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to use system's date/time which is in *mm/dd/yy* format in code. But the problem is that the time that I am getting is not in ate/time format. So I want to change it to CTime format so that I can use it. How is this going to be possible? **How can I convert the CString into CTIme format?**

Regards,

Mohan

Comment: exact duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411967/convert-cstring-to-ctime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample for your issue is as follows:

```
   COleDateTime myDtTime;
   CTime sysTime;
   if(myDtTime.ParseDateTime(strTimestampOther))
   {
          SYSTEMTIME st;
         if(myDtTime.GetAsSystemTime(st))
         {
               sysTime = st;
           }
   }
   else
   ASSERT(FALSE);
```