# want to convert ColeDateTime to CTime

Tags: mfc, ctime, coledatetime

I am reading a datetime from database in a `ColeDateTime` format. I want to convert it to `CTime` to get the date month year and time.

```
CString repDt; //**this will hold the datetime which i read from Database**

COleDateTime dt; 
//**my datetime format is mm/dd/yyyy.**

dt.ParseDateTime(repDt);   **//this line of code gives exception**

CTime t(dt.GetYear(), dt.GetMonth(), dt.GetDay(), dt.GetHour(),
        dt.GetMinute(), dt.GetSecond());
m_time=t.GetTime();
```

Please give me some solution how could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to convert first the repDT to DATE.

Answer (score 4):

The `CTime` constructor accepts both `SYSTEMTIME` and `DBTIMESTAMP` structures, so both these will work:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
if (dt.GetAsSystemTime(st))
    t = CTime(st);
```

,

```
DBTIMESTAMP dbts;
if (dt.GetAsDBTIMESTAMP(dbts))
    t = CTime(dbts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
COleDateTime dt=COleDateTime(2013, 12, 12,12,12,56);
CTime ctime;
SYSTEMTIME systime;
dt.GetAsSystemTime(systime);
ctime = CTime(systime);
```